# Set working directory Spring Boot executable jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a possibility to set the working directory for a Spring Boot executable jar?

For example when configuring property `logging.file.path` or `spring.pid.file` with a relative path it will be relative to the location of the jar.

The reason for this possibility comes in handy is that the jar is placed in a directory structure as the following:

```
my-app/
├── config
│   └── application.properties
├── lib
│   └── my-app.jar
├── log
│   └── my-app.log
├── pid
│   └── application.pid
└── var
```

Would be nice to configure the working direcotry at `/apps/my-app` and set `logging.file.path=log` so log files are written to `/apps/my-app/log`

The application is started as systemd service. The file looks like the following.

```
[Unit]
Description=my-app
After=network.target consul.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=app-user
Environment=JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx64M'
ExecStart=/apps/my-app/lib/my-app.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Tried setting working directory in systemd service file:

```
WorkingDirectory=/apps/my-app
```

This didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `WorkingDirectory` does work out if using the `-jar` option in combination with the fat jar.

So my solution for now will be like:

```
[Unit]
Description=my-app
After=network.target consul.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=app-user
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx64M"
WorkingDirectory=/apps/my-app
ExecStart=java $JAVA_OPTS -jar lib/my-app.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I am setting `WorkingDirectory` to the directory where my uber jar is. How do I know it doesn't work? My spring boot application is not able to find `application-prod.yml`. But when I run the command in the directory it works.

Comment: I had to use `ExecStart=/bin/java ...` as systemd requires an absolute path the for executable, but then it worked for me.